# How to TRIM in Oracle to only return the capital letter from a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string in a table say `xyzApqr`.

I want to trim the string and only output A.

The left and right trim values are different for different rows. How can you apply trim function in that case or is there any other way to do it.

'A' represents any set of characters that needs to be extracted from the column.

Comment: You really need to give more information about how you identify "A".  Try explaining the rules and giving some real examples.

Comment: There is too little information in your question to give you an answer. Could you edit the question and add some more sample data, and also the rules that determine what to extract?

Comment: You need to explain the logic that determines the value to extract - are xyzand pqr constant? if not how do they vary? is it the only capital letter you want? the 4th letter from the left? the right?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a technical question about _how_ to do it. Rather, it sounds like you are asking us to determine the logic for you.  But that's not for us to say, we don't know what your data is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME, INSTR(COLUMN_NAME, 'xyz')+2, INSTR(COLUMN_NAME, 'pqr')-3) AS OUTPUT FROM  TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
select regexp_replace(
         column_name,
         '^xyz(.*)pqr$',
         '\1')
from employees;
```

Comment: This would only work for that specific input, adding more letters or changing them doesn't give a desired output

Comment: It works for the case of removing a leading "xyz" and trailing "pqr", regardless of the number of characters between, which appears to be the main issue. "xyz" and "pqr" can also be replaced with arbitrary expressions that are concatanated in to form the second parameter, so it's pretty flexible. No idea whether what's actually wanted is "remove the first and last three characters", of course. Badly defined problem.

Comment: Absolutely, however i have a feeling this will never be clarified by the person asking the question so we may never know.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to only select the capitalised letter.

You can use a combination of `LTRIM`, `RTRIM`, `TRANSLATE`, `UPPER`, `RPAD` & `LENGTH`

```
SELECT name, LTRIM(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(name,LTRIM(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(name,UPPER(name),RPAD(' ',LENGTH(UPPER(name)))))) ,RPAD(' ',LENGTH(UPPER(name)))))) AS "Diff"
FROM yourtable
```

Input:

```
name
xyzApqr
```

Output:

```
name     Diff
xyzApqr  A
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/262f92/2/0